# PyVISA cannot write hex characters above 7F

Tags: python, serial-port, visa, pyvisa

I want to use PyVISA to communicate via RS232 with a Neslab RTE-111 water bath. I can find the instrument, but I cannot communicate with it because the pyvisa 'write' command gives an error when I try to send any hex character that is larger than '7F'. Unfortunately the water bath requires sending commands such as "CA 00 01 F0 02 01 2C DF".

The code is below.

```
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL::INSTR')
inst.write('\xca\x00\x01\x20\x00\xde')
```

This gives the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 223, in write
    count = self.write_raw(message.encode(enco))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xca' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

The write command seems to work fine for hex values below \x7f. Any ideas on how to send, say, '\xca'?

Comment: Try buffer_write.

Comment: or try write_binary_values()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the folks at pyvisa github page, I figured it out. The water bath instrument expects communication through direct bytes, thus the default commands from pyvisa do not work. It is necessary to use commands that write bytes directly, without any extra termination characters or anything of the sort.

To write to the instrument:

```
inst.write_raw(b'\xca\x00\x01\x20\x00\xde')
```

To read the instrument:

```
inst.read_bytes(#bytes)
```