# Establishing communication with device through RS232 using PySerial or PyVisa

Tags: python, serial-port, hex, pyvisa

Trying to communicate with a McPherson 747 Device Controller for the Filter Wheel on a lab instrument. It is connected to the lab computer through RS232 to usb. I've connected and communicated with other devices through serial before.

It seems that for a read request, I need to send an enquiry and header and then the Device will acknowledge and send data.

The manual for the Device says that all data is exchanged in ASCII format. Though there are also a few tables in the manual that has inputs in Hex ASCII code. The manual says that a three-byte enquiry is Hex 4E2105 or text N!< ENQ >. Acknowledge is Hex 4E2106 or text N!< ACK > . The header is a mix of several Hex ASCII inputs for reading and writing based on what information the user wants.

The issue I am having is when I code the serial information and send the enquire input, it always sends an error due to communication with the device. I am unfamiliar with Hex. Do I need to be sending the entire enquire, headeras one input, or can I send them separately?  I can also try to set up communication with PyVisa but I've gotten similar errors.

Through serial:

```
import codecs
import serial
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(port='COM1', 
                        baudrate = 9600, 
                        timeout = None,
                        xonxoff = False,
                        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                        )
    ser.close()
    string = '4E2105'
    enquire = codecs.decode(string,'hex')
    ser.open()
    ser.write(enquire); #ascii intput for pressing enter on keyboard
    ser.read_until(size=None) #reads out feedback until no data is left
    ser.close()
    msg = f"Program communication initialized"
    print(msg)
except Exception as ex:
    msg = f"Error: {ex}"
    print(msg)

Error: could not open port 'COM1': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
```

Through Pyvisa:

```
import pyvisa
import serial
import codecs

string = '4E2105'
enquire = codecs.decode(string,'hex')
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
# ('ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL2::INSTR', 'GPIB0::12::INSTR')
inst = rm.open_resource('asrl1::instr')
inst.write_termination='\r'
inst.read_termination='\r'
inst.baud_rate = 9600
inst.data_bits = 8
inst.parity = visa.constants.Parity.none
inst.flow_control = visa.constants.VI_ASRL_FLOW_NONE
inst.write(enquire)
print(inst.query("N!<ENQ>"))
rm.close()

VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.
```

Comment: "*Establishing communication with device through RS232 or pyvisa*" -- The former is a hardware interface/protocol, and the later is a software package.  Why do you think they are mutually exclusive (when they are not)?   IOW you seem to be confused as to the name of the software interfaces you're using, e.g. the [pySerial API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html).

Comment: "*I am unfamiliar with Hex."* -- Hexadecimal is simply a number system to represent values.  Just like binary or decimal.  "*Hex ASCII code*" maybe an oxymoron.   The numeric values for ASCII codes can be expressed as decimal, binary, octal, or hexadecimal.

Comment: Did you try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373840/803359)?